# Insert command without id postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

In mySQL i am able to do

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name1, column_name2) VALUES('John', 'Doe);
```

As you can see I do not have to mention the ID, how would I do this in postgreSQL.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming ID is [serial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (i.e. PostgreSQL equivalent of auto-increment), you can return the just-generated value using the [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-insert.html) statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Approach #1:**
You can declare your ID column as [Serial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html)
In this case it will create an implicit sequence for your column.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
   ID     serial   NOT NULL,
   column1 type,
   column2 type
}
```

**Approach #2:**
Or you can manually define a sequence and then assign its next value as Default value for the column.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence START 1;

CREATE TABLE MyTable
       (
       ID     integer   DEFAULT nextval('my_sequence'::regclass) NOT NULL,
       column1 type,
       column2 type
       }
```

Comment: those approaches don't work me and try to insert duplicate value :(

Answer (score 3):

This is not because of `mysql` that happens. You can make such this kind of query because you have set `id` as an `auto_increment` column

You can actually do the same thing in postgreSQL by using [the serial pseudo data type instead](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

Example of primary column serial

```
id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
```